# Assign all VLANs on a same port on HP procurve switch

Tags: hp-procurve, switch

i'm looking for this information for a few hours on the web but i still can't find the answer.

I have a few HP2610 switches (no stacked) and i want to assign all VLANs to switches interconnection ports. That means that i want all my number 23 ports to belong to all VLANs, in a tagged manner.

It was pretty simple to do that on a cheaper switches i worked on before and i'm amazed that i should do that manually on each vlan i define on hp procurve switch.

Thanks for any help !
Alex

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set up a trunk port?

Comment: Not really a trunk port, since a trunk port, according to hp terms, is an aggregation of a few ports (lacp ...). I just want configure an assignation all vlans <-> one tagged port

Answer (score 2):

You can only allow defined vLANs on particular ports. So you have to define the vLANs first, then assign them as tagged to port 23. This is a little different from Cisco switches where you only have to define the vLAN, and by default all ports can use all vLANs.

Answer (score 0):

When you put all the vlans on a specific port this is actually called tagging on HP switches. You tag all the vlans you require to be passed through on the specific port. I believe this is what joeqwery was trying to say when he mentioned trunk port which is what it's called on Cisco switches.